# Implementing a Linked List Stack and Queue, and I don't know if the code I have set up is efficient enough

Tags: java, stack, queue, linked-list

Been working on an implementation for Linked list Queue and Stack classes for an assignment. I've tested both of these and they appear to be working, but I'm worried that some parts of the implementation can be done better than I currently have set up, and I don't wanna get points taken off for inefficient code.

Here's the classes I have set up:

Node

```
public class Node {
Node next;
Car car;

/**
 * A node object, used for the creation of LinkedLists.
 * @param car
 */
public Node(Car car)
{
    next = null;
    this.car = car;
}
}
```

Stack

```
public class LStack {
Node head = null;

/**
 * Adds a car object to the list
 * @param car = the car object to be added
 */
public void push(Car car)
{
    Node oldHead = head;
    head = new Node(car);
    head.next = oldHead;
}

/**
 * Removes the top car from the list
 * @return the car at the top of the list
 */
public Car pop()
{
    Car headCar = head.car;
    head = head.next;
    return headCar;
}

/**
 * Checks if the list is empty
 * @return whether or not the list is empty
 */
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (head == null);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return the size of the list
 */
public int size()
{
    Node nextNode = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (nextNode != null)
    {
        count++;
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
    }
    return count;
}

/**
 * Displays the list of car license plate information
 */
public void display()
{
    Node nextNode = head;
    while (nextNode != null)
    {
        System.out.print(nextNode.car.getLicense() + "|");
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void reverseStack()
{
    // not implemented yet
}
}
```

Queue

```
public class LQueue {
Node head = null;

/**
 * Adds a car object to the list
 * 
 * @param car
 *            = the car object to be added
 */
public void insert(Car car) {
    Node current = head;
    if (current != null) {
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Node(car);
    }
    else
    {
        head = new Node(car);
    }
}

/**
 * Removes the top car from the list
 * 
 * @return the car at the top of the list
 */
public Car remove() {
    Car headCar = head.car;
    head = head.next;
    return headCar;
}

/**
 * Checks if the list is empty
 * 
 * @return whether or not the list is empty
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return the size of the list
 */
public int size() {
    Node nextNode = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (nextNode != null) {
        count++;
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
    }
    return count;
}

/**
 * Displays the list of car license plate information
 */
public void display() {
    Node nextNode = head;
    while (nextNode != null) {
        System.out.print(nextNode.car.getLicense() + "|");
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void reverseQueue() {

}
}
```

and the Car class isn't really important, it just stores license plate information in a string.

Mostly I'm worried about the ones I have set up with the While loops, I'm not sure if there's a more memory efficient way of implementing those. Is there a more standardized way of setting these up that I may have missed?

Comment: Consider taking this to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I would change is that I'd make `LQueue` keep references to both the head and the tail of the queue. This way you'd be able to `insert()` in constant time, without having to iterate over all existing elements.

Also, both `size()` methods can be made to run in constant time if you so wished: keep track of the current size in a member variable, increment on `insert()` and decrement on `remove()`.

Answer (score 3):

The only two things I can think of are:

1. Keep track of the number of elements in the list with an int that increments on add and decrements on remove.  This would make the size() method instant.  All you would have to do is return that int value.
2. For the queue, keep track of the tail with a Node reference much like you do the head.  That way you don't have to iterate through the list to find the end of the list.  The tail would just always be the last added Node.  This would allow you to not have to iterate through the list every time you want to add something; instead you could just add it to the end of that tail.